# How to pass Observable<string> to firebase.firestore.collection?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I have a function which takes a parameter of type Observable

- essentially I want to pass an id, the matchId, and return the Collection reference from firebase with that id

  import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

  public matchLineupRef: firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;

  ```
  getMatch(matchId:Observable<string>): firebase.firestore.DocumentReference {

         return this.matchesRef.doc(matchId);
    }
  ```

Here's the error I'm getting

- Argument of type 'Observable' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
- return this.matchesRef.doc(matchId);

Is there anyway I can convert the Observable to a normal string before calling return this.matchesRef.doc(matchId); or perhaps a different firebase.firestore.CollectionReference function to pass the Observable ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unclear why you are passing an `Observable` to the function.

Either you can work with:

- [`firstValueFrom`](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise#firstvaluefrom) to get the first value without waiting for the `Observable` to be completed, or
- [`lastValueFrom`](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise#lastvaluefrom) to get the last value when the `Observable` is completed.

Note that, this requires your `getMatch` method to convert it as an asynchronous function.

```
import {
  lastValueFrom
} from 'rxjs';

async getMatch(matchId:Observable<string>): Promise<firebase.firestore.DocumentReference> {
  let value = await lastValueFrom(matchId);

  return this.matchesRef.doc(matchId);
}
```

For the caller, you need `await` and make sure the method that call the `getMatch` method is asynchronous.

```
async callerFunction() {
  let doc = await getMatch(/* Provide matchId observable */);
}
```

---

Another approach you may consider is waiting until the Observable is returned/completed and emitting value/perform action via [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) operator.

Note that, your `getMatch` method requires returning an `Observable<firebase.firestore.DocumentReference>` value.

```
import {
  of,
  switchMap
} from 'rxjs';

getMatch(matchId:Observable<string>): Observable<firebase.firestore.DocumentReference> {
  return matchId
    .pipe(switchMap((x) => of(this.matchesRef.doc(matchId)));
}
```

For the caller, you need to subscribe to the `Observable`.

```
getMatch(/* Provide matchId observable */)
  .subscribe({
    next: (response) => {
      // Action handling for observable returned
      let doc = response;
    },
    error: (err) => {
      // Action handling for error (observable) returned
    }
  });
```

Comment: [Sample Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-lnc5eb?file=src%2Fmain.ts)